# How to run Apache Spark on all available Nodes for Test Network Connectivity

Tags: apache-spark

I have a requirement to validate network reachability from all Nodes in the Cloudera CDH6.3 cluster to ensure that other networks are able to connect from all nodes in the cluster.

Is it possible to make Spark to run on all nodes with some spark-submit config so that from all nodes I can use TCP connections to other network host and port.

Answer (score 2):

The number of executors would control the fan-out of the nodes of the cluster that run a job

`spark-submit --num-executors=N`

But I would use Ansible for a much simpler mass `telnet`/`nc` port check

Comment: Thanks for your response, I cant use telnet/nc check directly to all nodes as from dev team we dont have access to all nodes but with spark we can reach all nodes.

Comment: Well, if you have access to run any command within Spark code, then you effectively can do remote code execution to give yourself access ;)

Comment: Technically, `--num-executors=N` will try to start N executors on all reachable nodes, not validate that N nodes are reachable. In CDH context, node connectivity is validated by Cloudera agents heartbeating back to Cloudera Manager.

Comment: @mazaneicha True, but that would be YARN health checks

Comment: @OneCricketeer not even YARN, host agent is a python script sending basic host health info.

Comment: @mazaneicha I am aware how they work, but just because host is healthy doesn't mean Spark can deploy to it.